# What is the correct Java properties file translation of this XML configuration?

Tags: java, log4j2, properties-file

## Context

I've been searching for documentation specific to configuration log4j2 using Java properties files, but all I can find are a few rather basic examples. Most documentation I find, if it even exists, shows how to do log4j2 configuration in an XML file. More specifically I need to configure a `DynamicThresholdFilter` filter in a Java properties file.

I found this example DynamicThresholdFilter XML configuration in the [log4j2 manual](https://logging.apache.org/log4j/log4j-2.2/manual/filters.html).

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Configuration status="warn" name="MyApp" packages="">
  <DynamicThresholdFilter key="loginId" defaultThreshold="ERROR"
                          onMatch="ACCEPT" onMismatch="NEUTRAL">
    <KeyValuePair key="User1" value="DEBUG"/>
  </DynamicThresholdFilter>
  <Appenders>
    <RollingFile name="RollingFile" fileName="logs/app.log"
                 filePattern="logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz">
      <BurstFilter level="INFO" rate="16" maxBurst="100"/>
      <PatternLayout>
        <pattern>%d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n</pattern>
      </PatternLayout>
      <TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy />
    </RollingFile>
  </Appenders>
  <Loggers>
    <Root level="error">
      <AppenderRef ref="RollingFile"/>
    </Root>
  </Loggers>
</Configuration>
```

I attempted to translate this configuration to Java properties syntax, but I haven't got it quite right.

```
status = warn
name = MyApp
packages =

dynamicThresholdFilter.key = loginId
dynamicThresholdFilter.defaultThreshold = ERROR
dynamicThresholdFilter.onMatch = ACCEPT
dynamicThresholdFilter.onMismatch = NEUTRAL
dynamicThresholdFilter.Pairs.0.key = User1
dynamicThresholdFilter.Pairs.0.value = DEBUG

appender.rolling.type = RollingFile
appender.rolling.name = RollingFile
appender.rolling.fileName = logs/app.log
appender.rolling.filePattern = logs/app-%d{MM-dd-yyyy}.log.gz
appender.rolling.filter.burst.type = BurstFilter
appender.rolling.filter.burst.level = INFO
appender.rolling.filter.burst.rate = 16
appender.rolling.filter.burst.maxBurst = 100
appender.rolling.layout.type = PatternLayout
appender.rolling.layout.pattern = %d %p %c{1.} [%t] %m%n
appender.rolling.policies.type = Policies
appender.rolling.policies.time.type = TimeBasedTriggeringPolicy

rootLogger.level = error
rootLogger.appenderRef.rolling.ref = RollingFile
```

## Question

What is the correct Java properties translation of the above XML configuration?

Comment: Why you don't want to use the XML configuration?

Comment: @aled this is my first assignment with a new team. At this point I'd rather conform than tell the team they're doing it wrong.

Comment: "but I haven't got it quite right." be more specific. Are there errors? What is the result?

Comment: They're *not* 'doing it wrong'. They're just using a different format. You might be able to persuade them that it would be better to use this XML configuration as-is rather than via an error-prone translation step by you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The properties configuration factory in 2.x requires you to specify a `type` property for each sub-component (corresponding to a complex XML element). At the same time the prefix you use for a sub-component does not matter:

```
filter.dynamic.type = DynamicThresholdFilter
filter.dynamic.key = loginId
filter.dynamic.defaultThreshold = ERROR
filter.dynamic.onMatch = ACCEPT
filter.dynamic.onMismatch = NEUTRAL
filter.dynamic.p0.type = KeyValuePair
filter.dynamic.p0.key = User1
filter.dynamic.p0.value = DEBUG
```

**Remark**: in 3.x we'll switch to [`jackson-dataformat-properties`](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson-dataformats-text/tree/2.17/properties) to provide a more "standard" mapping between XML and properties (cf. [PR#2170](https://github.com/apache/logging-log4j2/pull/2170)) at the cost of additional dependencies for fans of the properties format.

In this case the mapping will be more straightforward and you only need to add a `type` property for **empty** elements:

```
DynamicThresholdFilter.key = loginId
DynamicThresholdFilter.defaultThreshold = ERROR
DynamicThresholdFilter.onMatch = ACCEPT
DynamicThresholdFilter.onMismatch = NEUTRAL
DynamicThresholdFilter.KeyValuePair[1].key = User1
DynamicThresholdFilter.KeyValuePair[1].value = DEBUG
```

The `log4j-config-properties` artifact will be available starting with version `3.0.0-beta2`.